# Refactoring to make code open for extensions but closed for modifications

Tags: c#, coding-style, solid-principles, open-closed-principle

For my project purpose I need to send metrics to AWS.

I have main class called SendingMetrics.

```
private CPUMetric _cpuMetric;
private RAMMetric _ramMetric;
private HDDMetric _hddMetric;
private CloudWatchClient _cloudWatchClient(); //AWS Client which contains method Send() that sends metrics to AWS

public SendingMetrics()
{
    _cpuMetric = new CPUMetric();
    _ramMetric = new RAMMetric();
    _hddMetric = new HDDMetric();
    _cloudwatchClient = new CloudwatchClient();
    InitializeTimer();
}

private void InitializeTimer()
{
   //here I initialize Timer object which will call method SendMetrics() each 60 seconds.
}

private void SendMetrics()
{
    SendCPUMetric();
    SendRAMMetric();
    SendHDDMetric();
}

private void SendCPUMetric()
{
    _cloudwatchClient.Send("CPU_Metric", _cpuMetric.GetValue());
}

private void SendRAMMetric()
{
    _cloudwatchClient.Send("RAM_Metric", _ramMetric.GetValue());
}

private void SendHDDMetric()
{
    _cloudwatchClient.Send("HDD_Metric", _hddMetric.GetValue());
}
```

Also I have CPUMetric, RAMMetric and HDDMetric classes that looks pretty much similar so I will just show code of one class.

```
internal sealed class CPUMetric
{
    private int _cpuThreshold;

    public CPUMetric()
    {
        _cpuThreshold = 95;
    }

    public int GetValue()
    {
        var currentCpuLoad = ... //logic for getting machine CPU load
        if(currentCpuLoad > _cpuThreshold)
        {
             return 1;
        }
        else 
        {
             return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

So the problem I have is that clean coding is not satisfied in my example. I have 3 metrics to send and if I need to introduce new metric I will need to create new class, initialize it in SendingMetrics class and modify that class and that is not what I want. I want to satisfy Open Closed principle, so it is open for extensions but closed for modifications.

What is the right way to do it? I would move those send methods (SendCPUMetric, SendRAMMetric, SendHDDMetric) to corresponding classes (SendCPUMetric method to CPUMetric class, SendRAMMEtric to RAMMetric, etc) but how to modfy SendingMetrics class so it is closed for modifications and if I need to add new metric to not change that class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your design is almost correct. You got 3 data retriever and 1 data sender. So it's easy to add more metric (more retriever) (open for extensions) without affecting current metrics (closed for modifications), you just need a bit more refactor to reduce duplicated code.

Instead of have 3 metrics classes look very similar. Only below line is different

```
var currentCpuLoad = ... //logic for getting machine CPU load
```

You can create a generic metric like this

```
internal interface IGetMetric
{
    int GetData();
}

internal sealed class Metric
{
    private int _threshold;
    private IGetMetric _getDataService;

    public Metric(IGetMetric getDataService)
    {
        _cpuThreshold = 95;
        _getDataService = getDataService;
    }

    public int GetValue()
    {
        var currentCpuLoad = _getDataService.GetData();
        if(currentCpuLoad > _cpuThreshold)
        {
             return 1;
        }
        else 
        {
             return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Then just create 3 GetMetric classes to implement that interface. This is just 1 way to reduce the code duplication. You can also use inheritance (but I don't like inheritance). Or you can use a Func param.

UPDATED: added class to get CPU metric

```
internal class CPUMetricService : IGetMetric
{
    public int GetData() { return ....; }
}
internal class RAMMetricService : IGetMetric
{
    public int GetData() { return ....; }
}
public class AllMetrics
{
    private List<Metric> _metrics = new List<Metric>()
    {
         new Metric(new CPUMetricService());
         new Metric(new RAMMetricService());
    }

    public void SendMetrics()
    {
         _metrics.ForEach(m => ....);
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you please show example of code with generic classes that will implement that interface?

Comment: I updated to include more code example. Also I remove generic type since you don't need that complexity.

Comment: Looks like the `AllMetrics` class still violates the OCP since it instantiates each `Metric`.

Comment: what you mean OCP?

Comment: OCP = Open Closed Principle. Thanks for the answer Alex, I did it that way. @jaco0646 Can you share how to do it to not violate the OCP?

Answer (score 1):

In object oriented languages like C# the Open Closed Principle (OCP) is usually achieved by using the concept of polymorphism. That is that objects of the same kind react different to one and the same message. Looking at your class "SendingMetrics" it's obvious that the class works with different types of "Metrics". The good thing is that your class "SendingMetrics" talks to a all types of metrics in the same way by sending the message "getData". Hence you can introduce a new abstraction by creating an Interface "IMetric" that is implemented by the concrete types of metrics. That way you decouple your "SendingMetrics" class from the concrete metric types wich means the class does not know about the specific metric types. It only knows IMetric and treats them all in the same way wich makes it possible to add any new collaborator (type of metric) that implements the IMetric interface (open for extension) without the need to change the "SendingMetrics" class (closed for modification). This also requires that the objects of the different types of metrics are not created within the "SendingMetrics" class but e.g. by a factory or outside of the class and being injected as IMetrics.

In addition to using inheritance to enable polymorphism and achiving OCP by introducing the interface IMetric you can also use inheritance to remove redundancy. Which means you can introduce an abstract base class for all metric types that implements common behaviour that is used by all types of metrics.